# Linux tar command with exclude

Tags: linux, tar, exclude

> I want to create tar file of a folder
>   but this folder contains some tar.gz
>   files like abc.tar.gz, pqr.tar.gz
>   which i don't want to include so how
>   to exclude this files while making the
>   tar

Answer (score 5):

```
 --exclude=PATTERN
      When performing operations, `tar' will skip files that match
      PATTERN.
```

---

```
--exclude="*.tar.gz"
```

---

```
 --exclude-from=FILE
 -X FILE
      Similar to --exclude, except `tar' will use the list of patterns
      in the file FILE.
```

---

```
--exclude-from="File.txt"
```

**File.txt**

```
abc.tar.gz
prq.tar.gz
```

Comment: thanks, it helpful to understand the command more clearly

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
find ./ -name '*.tar.gz' > /tmp/excludefiles
tar -czvf newarchive.tar.gz -X /tmp/excludefiles foldertotar/
```

I haven't test it. It's only idea how to solve it.

EDITED:

It's even simpler:

```
tar -czvf newarchivename.tar.gz --exclude '*.tar.gz' foldertobetarred/
```

This solution is tested and works.

Comment: i am not clear about how to use this command

Answer (score 0):

You can use the --exclude functionality in tar

```
@tmp$ ls test
abc.tar.gz  adfd  asdfd  dfcvdf  dfdf  efdfefef  pqr.tar.gz  test
@tmp$ tar -cvzf test.tar.gz test --exclude="*.tar.gz"
test/
test/adfd
test/dfcvdf
test/test/
test/test/abcd
test/efdfefef
test/dfdf
test/asdfd
```